# Snapdragon or Exynos?

Tags: updates

I have Samsung Galaxy S7 and I want to check if I have a Snapdragon or Exynos chipset. I need this info because I plan to install Android Pie or 10 and I need to know exactly which chipset the phone has. My baseband is G930SKU3ETG1, Build number R16NWG930SKSU3ETG2, yet back casing SM-G930P. SNAPDROGON or EXYNOS? It has already been rooted with android 8.0.0.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why don't you just install an system or cpu info app that checks the CPU and shows the results?

Answer (score 1):

Install AIDA64 from the Play Store, which is free (with advertising). The CPU tab will show you exactly what SoC you have, and what the cores are. For example, my Samsung Galaxy S8 shows:

SoC Model  Samsung Eyxnos 9 Octa (8895)

Core Architecture 4x ARM Cortex-A53 @ 1690 MHz 4x Samsung Exymos M2 @ 2314 MHz